# JQuery event, text changed but NOT by keyboard - how to catch it?

Tags: input, jquery

**Scenario:** A humble text field, marked as *readonly*. When clicked a datepicker appears. When you click a date from the datepicker it populates that text field with something like: 10/05/2013.

**Problem:** I need to reformat the text from 10/05/2013 to Friday, May 10, 2013. To do this I need to catch when the value inside the text field is changed. This is where the problem begins. The typical events are:

- `change`: can't use this because it requires the text field to come OUT of focus (assuming it was in focus) before checking the difference;
- `keyup`: can't use this because the user isn't pressing any keys o.O
- `paste`: no pasting being done here, not by the user at least
- `input`: I was hoping this'd work, but it doesn't. I'm not actually quite sure when this event is supposed to fire, but it's not helping me here :(

My code looks something like:

```
$('input[type="text"]').datepicker('hide');
// That sets up the datepicker (as per a plugin) to pop up
// when I click the text box, working fine :D

$('input[type="text"]').live('change keyup paste input', function() {
    // Trying everything out of desperation :/
    alert($(this).value());
});
```

**Question:** How can I catch when the text in this input field changes under in the scenario described?

Comment: use the onblur  event? But why an event , why not inject your method in the part where the datepicker updates the textbox? Or even nbetter: cnfigure the datepicker to display the correct format.

Comment: format the datepicker?
visit this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: You should hook something up to your datepicker-call. jQuerys datepicker have an onSelect: . Even better format the date in the datepicker first. Read more about it on: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Ooo I was actually using a different datepicker (Bootstrap Datepicker) and their documentation showed some formatting, but not like in the examples below (so I assumed they didn't have it). The hooks for it were weird (it changed the text when I navigated months and years (even without selecting any o.O) and that wasn't picked up by its own change text function...). I never knew jquery had one, I'll use it instead :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just set the `dateFormat`?

```
$('input[type="text"]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD, M d, yy'   
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smq6C/4/)

Comment: Oops I was using a different datepicker that didn't format it like this for me. I guess this is an... indirect.. solution, I'll just change to your datepicker! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Madthew/9nw3f/

and follow this: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

in order to format your date.

If you leave 'hide' here:

```
$('input[type="text"]').datepicker('hide');
```

the calendar doesn't appear.

Comment: have you tried with different browser? How that can be possible!

Comment: Are you importing jquery and jquery UI correctly??? Maybe you are only importing jquery....

Comment: import:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>